# SSRS Counts for Different Statuses Based on Distinct IDs

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that contains two tables that are using the same dataset. The first table is grouped by an ID and lists the statuses and other details for each ID. There can be multiples of the same ID in this section of the report. The second table needs to count the number of each type of status based on distinct IDs. I also need a total of all distinct IDs. I have figured out the total of all distinct IDs, but not how to get the number of each status type based on distinct IDs. I cannot include my real data, but I have created some fake data to approximate my issue.

See the image for the data sample:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second table, you need to create a rowgroup that groups by `Status`.

Then set the first column in your table to `Status` and the second column will use an expression..

```
=COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!AppointmentID.Value)
```

For your final total, you can simply right-click your rowgroup and choose "Add Total --> After"

The report design (showing rowgroups) should look like this

[image]

This give the following output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting very frustrated, This worked perfectly!

Comment: No problem, just so you understand it, the distinct ID are counted with the rowgroup, so it shows the distinct IDs for the relevant status only.